# iPhone App Phone Call Situation

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, interface, interface-builder

When a phone call occurs, my app moves down, and the bottom of the app is cut off slightly.  Is there anyway to shrink or resize that whole view when a call occurs.

Preferably through interface builder.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987605/iphone-programming-in-call-status-bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, your application window does shrink its subview. For example, if you have a status bar so the frame of your root view is (0,20,320,460), then if the in-call status bar is on, then the frame becomes (0,40,320,**440**).

Then why does the bottom of your app seem to be cut off? It's simply because the root view autoresizes its content in that way. For example, its `autoresizingMask` property says it has a fixed top margin and a fixed content height. So,

- If you want to 'squeeze' the view, try fixing both top and bottom margins and having flexible content heights.
- If you want the in-call status bar to look as if it goes over your app, fix the content heights and the bottom margin, and have a flexible top margin.
- If you have a fixed top margin and a fixed content height, then your app will seem to slide down.

Comment: I'm sorry but where are these features at?  I only have one view, so were do I go to do this

Comment: Select the superview, and in the Window Size pane of the inspector, there is 'Autoresizing' section which graphically represents the settings. Click on the edges representing top/bottom margins and the content height so only the top margin is deactivated.